# Link Jade agents with JavaFX GUI

Tags: java, javafx, agents-jade

I create an agent with some functionlity, and a GUI in JavaFX, but when I try to connect both of them appear the following error:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Error: class vom.CAPlatform is not a subclass of javafx.application.Application
```

My agent is the following:

```
    import jade.core.SecureCloud.SecureCAPlatform;
import javafx.application.Application;
import sample.SecureCAController;

public class CAPlatform extends SecureCAPlatform {


    public void setup(){
        SecureCAController sa = new SecureCAController();
        sa.setAgent(this);
        sa.launch();
        //Application.launch(SecureCAController.class);
    }


}
```

And my controller:

```
    package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import vom.CAPlatform;

public class SecureCAController extends Application {

    private double xOffset;
    private double yOffset;
    public CAPlatform myAgent;



    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));

        root.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                xOffset = mouseEvent.getSceneX();
                yOffset = mouseEvent.getSceneY();
            }
        });


        root.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                primaryStage.setX(mouseEvent.getScreenX() - xOffset);
                primaryStage.setY(mouseEvent.getScreenY() - yOffset);
            }
        });


        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.setTitle("CA");
        Scene sceneNew = new Scene(root);
        sceneNew.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        primaryStage.setScene(sceneNew);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    public void setAgent(CAPlatform caPlatform) {
        myAgent = caPlatform;
    }
}
```

I created the GUI with the JavaFX and I try to implement to my agent.

Comment: Err... What is the point of those 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa' s?

Comment: sorry an error.

Comment: How are you running the application? It looks like you're trying to run a class that is not your main class.